# Запятую или двоеточие следует поставить в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, двоеточие

Вопрос следующий: запятую или двоеточие следует поставить в предложении?

"Именно с этого фильма советское кино задышало и заиграло красками(: ,) мы увидели живых людей, а не картонных персонажей".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В бессоюзном сложном предложении ставится запятая, если его части близки между собой по значению: *Метель не утихала, небо не прояснялось* (П.); *Поезд ушёл быстро, его огни скоро исчезли, через минуту уже не было слышно шума* (Ч.).

Запятая в таких случаях транслирует обычную перечислительную интонацию, и отношения между простыми предложениями никак не обозначаются. Такой вариант возможен и в предложении из вопроса, но, на мой взгляд, он неудачен, так как между частями есть взаимосвязь. Почему "советское кино задышало"? Потому что ушли шаблоны, лозунги и "картонные персонажи". В данном случае используется **двоеточие**.

> 6. Если вторая часть бессоюзного сложного предложения указывает основание или причину того, о чем говорится в первой части, то между частями ставится двоеточие (между частями можно вставить причинные союзы *потому что, так как, поскольку* и т. п.)...

[**Двоеточие в бессоюзном сложном предложении**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=150,6) (Розенталь)

P. S. Часто вместо двоеточия можно увидеть **тире**. «Самые многочисленные случаи вариативности знаков препинания — параллельное употребление двоеточия и тире» (Справочник Розенталя, [***ДВОЕТОЧИЕ — ТИРЕ***](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=189)).

Comment: Я тоже склоняюсь к мысли,что там следует поставить двоеточие,потому как можно вставить союз"А ИМЕННО"."Советское кино задышало и заиграло красками,а именно: мы увидели живых людей."